# rawQuery() exact match

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using the following method to query my SQLite database with `LIKE` statement.

```
public List<Bean> getWords(String englishWord) {
        if(englishWord.equals(""))
            return new ArrayList<Bean>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " LIKE ? ORDER BY LENGTH(" + ENGLISH + ") LIMIT 100";

        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"%" + englishWord.trim() + "%"});

            List<Bean> wordList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String english = cursor.getString(1);
                String mal = cursor.getString(2);
                wordList.add(new Bean(english, bangla));
            }

            return wordList;
        } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

I would like to change the above code for that it will query for exact match. I tried to modify the code as below but I do not how to get the `mal` string.

```
public void getoneWords(String englishWord) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " =?";

        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{englishWord});

            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String english = cursor.getString(1);
                String mal = cursor.getString(2);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You sure index in `getString` is right?

Comment: The index is right, but Android studio is giving me message, variable `english` and `mal` is never used. How to use them?

Comment: You create a method `getoneWords()` with `void` return type  Why ? And now you are saying  variable `english` and `mal` is never used.  What exactly you trying to achieve here? Edit your question

Comment: I am self taught and have limited knowledge. The `getoneWords` is my attempt to modify from `getWords` because I know if I do not put any attempt, I will get many down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem myself.

```
public String getoneWords(String englishWord) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " =?";

        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String meaning = "";
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {englishWord});
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                meaning = cursor.getString(2);
            }
            return meaning;
        }finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `getoneWords` for what. You should return `mal` and `english` in this function.

```
return new Bean(english, mal);
```

If you need first word, just cursor.moveToFirst and delete while loop:

```
String english = cursor.getString(1);
String mal = cursor.getString(2);
return new Bean(english, mal);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getoneWords()` you are not returning the queried values.
As you have two return values you would either need to wrap them in a Pair or create a "holder" Object (e.g. `class Words(String english, String mal)`) for the return values.

If your Query returns multiple matches you would need to return a list of those Objects. Otherwise, your above Code would just return the last match.

So you need to alter your function to return the queried

```
public Pair<String,String> getoneWords(String englishWord) {
    Pair<String,String> result = null;
    ...
    if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
         String english = cursor.getString(1);
         String mal = cursor.getString(2);
         result = new Pair<String,String>(english, mal);
    }
    ... 
    return result;

}
```